# PHP returned JSON looks like HTML code

Tags: java, php, android, json

I have an Android app, and I send a Http request via `getJson()` method to get a generated JSON file from the web server. However, the result I always get in my Android app looks like this (looks like HTML, not like a JSON object):

```
I/System.out: <html><body><script type="text/javascript" src="/aes.js" ></script><script>function toNumbers(d){var e=[];d.replace(/(..)/g,function(d){e.push(parseInt(d,16))});return e}function toHex(){for(var d=[],d=1==arguments.length&&arguments[0].constructor==Array?arguments[0]:arguments,e="",f=0;f<d.length;f++)e+=(16>d[f]?"0":"")+d[f].toString(16);return e.toLowerCase()}var a=toNumbers("f655ba9d09a112d4968c63579db590b4"),b=toNumbers("98344c2eee86c3994890592585b49f80"),c=toNumbers("674bdf26f9a5fe3df1461aafc3120641");document.cookie="__test="+toHex(slowAES.decrypt(c,2,a,b))+"; expires=Thu, 31-Dec-37 23:55:55 GMT; path=/"; location.href="http://example.net/index.php?i=1";</script><noscript>This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your browser or use a browser with Javascript support</noscript></body></html>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
  $results = array(
      "result"   => "success",
      "username" => "some username",
      "projects" => "some other value"
  );
  header('Content-type: application/json');
  echo json_encode($results);
?>
```

**Connection method:**

```
public String getJSON(String url, int timeout) {
        HttpURLConnection c = null;
        try {
            URL u = new URL(url);
            c = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
            c.setRequestMethod("GET");
            c.setRequestProperty("Content-length", "0");
            c.setUseCaches(false);
            c.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
            c.setConnectTimeout(timeout);
            c.setReadTimeout(timeout);
            c.connect();
            int status = c.getResponseCode();

            switch (status) {
                case 200:
                case 201:
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(c.getInputStream()));
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    String line;
                    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line+"\n");
                    }
                    br.close();
                    return sb.toString();
            }

        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } finally {
            if (c != null) {
                try {
                    c.disconnect();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Call:

```
String data = getJSON("http://example.net", 10000);
// or String data = getJSON("http://example.net/index.php", 10000);
System.out.println(data);
```

The "example.net" URL is a valid URL, where it shows correctly the JSON file when opened in the browser.

**Question**: How do I obtain JSON file in an Android app, when Android's HttpURLConnection **doesn't** support JavaScript?

Comment: The clue is in the message in the source: `This site requires Javascript to work...`. When viewed in a browser, it sets a cookie and redirects to another page using Javascript. Without the browser, this step doesn't happen, so you're left with the raw HTML.

Comment: Aha, thanks, I did not notice that. Is there a way to trick the JS redirect then?

Comment: You can use http response codes (`301` permanent, `302` temporary) to redirect without needing any code run in the browser. This will also work with non-browsers if they support redirects. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/301

Comment: How do I obtain the path of the just generated file?

Comment: did you tried using volley or something?

Comment: No, I didn't know this library. I'll try it now.

Comment: It returns the same (html): `com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException: Value <html><body><script of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject`